# Dynamic Page/Replacing Content with a twist (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, dynamic, pageload

I'm wondering how hard it would be to dynamically replace content in a wordpress site through the use of JQuery.
This is the article I'm going off of:
http://css-tricks.com/6336-dynamic-page-replacing-content/

My basic idea was to change the elements referred to in their javascript file to the elements created in wordpress by default. This means changing page-wrap to wrapper, main-content to main-col, and guts to content.

<del>I ran into a speed bump when I tried replacing 'guts' though.  For some reason the page doesn't show the content anymore.
Anyway, after I get that sorted out,</del>

I figured it out.  I'll insert the code into my wordpress site and hope for the best.

one of the pages:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header></header>
              <div class="nav">
              <ul class="sf-menu">
                  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        </header>
        <section id="main-col">
            <div id="content">
            <h2>Home</h2>
            <p></p> 
            <p></p> 
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript that is inserted into the header:

```
/*
 * jQuery hashchange event - v1.2 - 2/11/2010
 * http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/
 * 
 * Copyright (c) 2010 "Cowboy" Ben Alman
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 * http://benalman.com/about/license/
 */
(function($,i,b){var j,k=$.event.special,c="location",d="hashchange",l="href",f=$.browser,g=document.documentMode,h=f.msie&&(g===b||g<8),e="on"+d in i&&!h;function a(m){m=m||i[c][l];return m.replace(/^[^#]*#?(.*)$/,"$1")}$[d+"Delay"]=100;k[d]=$.extend(k[d],{setup:function(){if(e){return false}$(j.start)},teardown:function(){if(e){return false}$(j.stop)}});j=(function(){var m={},r,n,o,q;function p(){o=q=function(s){return s};if(h){n=$('<iframe src="javascript:0"/>').hide().insertAfter("body")[0].contentWindow;q=function(){return a(n.document[c][l])};o=function(u,s){if(u!==s){var t=n.document;t.open().close();t[c].hash="#"+u}};o(a())}}m.start=function(){if(r){return}var t=a();o||p();(function s(){var v=a(),u=q(t);if(v!==t){o(t=v,u);$(i).trigger(d)}else{if(u!==t){i[c][l]=i[c][l].replace(/#.*/,"")+"#"+u}}r=setTimeout(s,$[d+"Delay"])})()};m.stop=function(){if(!n){r&&clearTimeout(r);r=0}};return m})()})(jQuery,this);

$(function() {

    var newHash      = "",
        $mainContent = $("#main-col"),
        $pageWrap    = $("#wrapper"),
        baseHeight   = 0,
        $el;

    $pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
    baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

    $("sf-menu").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

        newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

        if (newHash) {
            $mainContent
                .find("content")
                .fadeOut(200, function() {
                    $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + "#content", function() {
                        $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                            $pageWrap.animate({
                                height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                            });
                        });
                        $("sf-menu a").removeClass("current");
                        $("sf-menu a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");
                    });
                });
        };

    });

    $(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

Comment: Not hard if you know what you are doing. Try posting some actual code or a link to your beta site.

Comment: Okay, I added some of the code.

Comment: Okay, I got the page loading to work with a normal html document.  How should I go about testing this on wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change name into your css ID as well.. That is the only reason. If you have changed id in js and your php/html but not in css than defiantly it wont show any content.

So change #page-wrap to #wrapper and #main-content to #main-col and its done.

So overall you need to modify 3 files

Js, HTML/PHP and CSS

Comment: I figured out what I did wrong.  Do you know how I should test it in wordpress?

Comment: I have just added two days before same code in my new wordpress theme. You can get it work with same structure. provide code if you want exact code

Comment: Better if you can provide your code structure here. So can understand more and able to help you to make it work. Note: I am talking about your php/loop/page code wherever you want to use it.

Comment: I'm not completely sure.  My theme inserts the code in the header, but when I add a # to the url instead of removing content it just redirects to the home page.

Comment: One more thing:  I'm not sure about the ids I used.  For the nav there are multiple tags that confuse me.  First is 'nav', then inside of nav there is 'col-control', and in that is 'sf-menu', which is the ul holding all the links.

Comment: Can't help until you provide your code. Is it so difficult to provide code? than give at least your structure hint. All things are depended on structure and ID's. How could I know without knowing your structure? Give me some time. I will post here my code what I am using with this js

Comment: Okay here what I am using and it works fine without any problem.


`Find code in js near line#31
$("nav a").removeClass("current");
$("nav a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");

change id for yoru nav in place of #link and assign that id to nav // I am using <aside id="link"> instad of nav
$("#link a").removeClass("current");
$("#link a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");


<aside id="link">

 <!--[wordpress menu code here]-->

</aside>



<?php the_post(); ?>
 
 <!--[guts div start]-->
 <div id="guts">
  <!--[all content with your structure]-->
 </div>
 <!--[end of guts div]-->`

Comment: Okay I have just notice you are using below code for nav

'$("sf-menu a").removeClass("current");
                        $("sf-menu a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");'

But id is missing #

if you have sub tag in nav tag and there is no anchor tag except 'sf-menu' than it should work.